# javascript array filter very slow in REACT

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a custom listbox, a `div` that contains a vertical list of other `div` children. And I have `input` for search something else in the list. It's working but in large data, it's working very slowly.

Also search criterion produce dynamically with column chooser. How can i increase search performance.

**Firsly, prepare filter data for search and keeping state on the page load**

```
prepareFilterData(allData) {
  const filteredData = [];
  let columnChooser = JSON.parse(getItemFromLocalStorage("ColumnData"));
  allData.map(item => {
    var data = "";
    columnChooser.map(element => {
      var newData = { value: item[element.value], format: element.format };
      var filterItem = getFilterDataFormat(newData);
      data += filterItem + " ";
    });
    filteredData.push(data);
  });
  this.setState({
    filteredData: filteredData
  });
}
```

**Secondly, When user enter an char to `textbox`, i'm checking `filteredData`**

```
filterList() {
  const updatedList = this.state.allData.length > 0 ? this.state.allData : [];
  var filteredData = [];
  filteredData = updatedList.filter((item, index) => {
    const data = this.state.filteredData[index];
    return data.indexOf(this.state.searchInputValue) !== -1;
  });
  return filteredData;
}
```

This is `input` statement

```
<input 
  id="searchBox"
  type="text"
  className="filter-input empty"
  placeholder="Search"
  onChange={this.filterList}
  value={this.props.state.searchInputValue}
  style={{ width: "100%" }} />
```

Comment: To improve performance you would need limit the data you fetch and do something like infinite scroll or partial load of results. Would that work for you?

Comment: I give the limit to show data but my problem is searching for data.

Comment: Firstly, I really think you should take some time to look into what `map` and `forEach` do.  Also, `data.includes()` might be nice, but all of these are micro gains.  And why you're getting data from `this.state.filteredData[index]` instead of `item`, I'm not sure.  That's an extra lookup.

I think a better approach would be to ask what `this.state.allData.length` is?

Comment: `this.state.allData` is a `json array`.It's my data. I dont use `item` because of search criteria produce dynamically. so I'm checking `state` of `array` column.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution.

SOLUTION:

I create a `util.js` in my project, and I called `createFilter` `function`.

```
import Fuse from "fuse.js";
import { toTrLowerCase } from "./process";

function flatten(array) {
  return array.reduce((flat, toFlatten) => flat.concat(Array.isArray(toFlatten) ? flatten(toFlatten) : toFlatten), []);
}

export function getValuesForKey(key, item) {
  const keys = key.split(".");
  let results = [item];
  keys.forEach(_key => {
    const tmp = [];
    results.forEach(result => {
      if (result) {
        if (result instanceof Array) {
          const index = parseInt(_key, 10);
          if (!isNaN(index)) {
            return tmp.push(result[index]);
          }
          result.forEach(res => {
            tmp.push(res[_key]);
          });
        } else if (result && typeof result.get === "function") {
          tmp.push(result.get(_key));
        } else {
          tmp.push(result[_key]);
        }
      }
    });

    results = tmp;
  });

  // Support arrays and Immutable lists.
  results = results.map(r => (r && r.push && r.toArray ? r.toArray() : r));
  results = flatten(results);

  return results.filter(r => typeof r === "string" || typeof r === "number");
}

export function searchStrings(strings, term, { caseSensitive, fuzzy, sortResults, exactMatch } = {}) {
  strings = strings.map(e => e.toString());

  try {
    if (fuzzy) {
      if (typeof strings.toJS === "function") {
        strings = strings.toJS();
      }
      const fuse = new Fuse(
        strings.map(s => {
          return { id: s };
        }),
        { keys: ["id"], id: "id", caseSensitive, shouldSort: sortResults }
      );
      return fuse.search(term).length;
    }
    return strings.some(value => {
      try {
        if (!caseSensitive) {
          value = value.toLowerCase();
        }
        if (exactMatch) {
          term = new RegExp("^" + term + "$", "i");
        }
        if (value && value.search(term) !== -1) {
          return true;
        }
        return false;
      } catch (e) {
        return false;
      }
    });
  } catch (e) {
    return false;
  }
}

export function createFilter(term, keys, options = { caseSensitive: false, fuzzy: false, sortResults: false, exactMatch: false }) {
  debugger;
  return item => {
    if (term === "") {
      return true;
    }

    if (!options.caseSensitive) {
      term = term.toLowerCase();
    }

    const terms = term.split(" ");

    if (!keys) {
      return terms.every(term => searchStrings([item], term, options));
    }

    if (typeof keys === "string") {
      keys = [keys];
    }

    return terms.every(term => {
      // allow search in specific fields with the syntax `field:search`
      let currentKeys;
      if (term.indexOf(":") !== -1) {
        const searchedField = term.split(":")[0];
        term = term.split(":")[1];
        currentKeys = keys.filter(key => key.toLowerCase().indexOf(searchedField) > -1);
      } else {
        currentKeys = keys;
      }

      return currentKeys.some(key => {
        const values = getValuesForKey(key, item);
        values[0] = toTrLowerCase(values[0]);
        return searchStrings(values, term, options);
      });
    });
  };
}
```

And then i added `fuse.js` to `package.json`.

```
"fuse.js": "^3.0.0"
```

I called createFilter function like that... `term` is searching `value` `key`

`keysToFilter` is which `array` `column` you wanna search.

```
this.state.allData.filter(createFilter(term, this.state.keysToFilter));
```

Link: https://github.com/enkidevs/react-search-input

Answer (score 1):

Using a standard `for` loop can significantly increase the performance, especially in your case where you're using `indexOf` which is causing another iteration in your `filter`. The filter operation uses callbacks and it's often used because of the simpler syntax but it's these callback that make the operation to be slower especially on big data.

Read more [here](https://hackernoon.com/javascript-performance-test-for-vs-for-each-vs-map-reduce-filter-find-32c1113f19d7).

Comment: The `indexOf` is on a string.  And while using `for` is slightly faster, I've never seen it be a magic bullet.